# Anyone know who makes ICs labelled 'Hi'

Tags: microcontroller, identification

I took apart an old Huawei 3G wifi modem, hoping to leave the radio stuff, and find an off the shelf MCU in there.

Aside from an Atheros wifi chip, and a Hynix memory chip, the only other ones not to do with RF are:

Hi 6755RBC / 120 / HP0221122

And:

Hi 6331RBC / 381 / CP0051127

However, I can find nothing about them. Can't even establish which company this is.

The modem exposes an admin web page, so I'm sure one of those must be doing the business!

Comment: Give us a picture. Sometimes the packaging of the chips or the way the labeling is laid out is distinctive enough for someone to recognize.

Comment: Thanks both - I think Nick is correct (but I can't mark a comment as 'answered'). I shall post a photo when I have the board in hand. In any case, it means there's no hope of reprogramming such a device anyway.

Comment: You can't upvote answers yet, but you can accept the answer which best answers your question. Click the checkmark under the upvote/downvote arrows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be that Hi is Huawei. It could be an ASIC commissioned by Huawei. Sometimes, board-level manufacturers order standard chips with special markings. This is done to hinder reverse-engineering.

Answer (score 0):

[Holt IC](http://www.holtic.com/) prefixes their chips with HI, but they mainly do Avionics chips as well as some general RS-485 and CAN interface chips.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't think that's it.Out of interest, how did you find a company that uses a certain prefix (particularly one which is also a short and common English word!)

Comment: I happen to have worked with their chips.